# How to check if the ETH address is reported as fraudulent?

Tags: ether, etherscan

Is there any api that we check if an ETH address has reported as fraudulent in etherscan or any other similar services?

something like `Check Address` api in [bitcoinabuse](https://www.bitcoinabuse.com/api-docs).

Answer (score 2):

There are no public services for reporting fraudulent Ethereum addresses, or they would be next to useless.

Scammers are free to generate infinite number of Ethereum addresses for free.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the info directly from https://etherscan.io.

For example: https://etherscan.io/address/0xab8bd0d4eda57cd9ee5a058e498a791df13dfa65

An address (EOA or Contract) has different **labels** - good and bad - also they react very quickly, when a new fraudulent contract is found by the community. So, you have to load the HTML and extract the labels - it is not the API, but also quite easy to handle. One caveat is - etherscan use Cloudflare, so your requests could be blocked, as your custom HTTP library could have different SSL handshake as browsers. Then you would need to use a proxy like this: https://github.com/Carcraftz/TLS-Fingerprint-API

---

Though Mikko is right the scammer can generate lots of EOA addresses, but not the contract addresses, as deploying the contract is quite expensive.